# How to properly use multiple partial views with different models ASP CORE

Tags: asp.net, viewmodel, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have this in my cshtml file

```
<div class="login">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Login")
</div>
<div class="register">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Register")
</div>
```

And my partials look like this

_Login:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using project.Models

@model LoginViewModel
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    ...

    <button id="loginBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>   
</form>
```

_Register:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using project.Models

@model RegisterViewModel
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    ...

    <button id="registerBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>   
</form>
```

My idea is to have one of the two divs always with display:none (Initially it's the second one with this property), so the user interacts with only one form at a time. However, when I click the button [Log In] I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'cartoondrawme.Models.AccountViewModels.LoginViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'cartoondrawme.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel'.

My question is, do I have a flaw and what is it, or is this method entirely wrong, in which case - what is the right way?

I don't understand how the submit button from one form triggers the other form. If I delete the second div, it works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Seems to be an aspnet mvc core thing. Used to work fine with as.net mvc.  I will let you know if I come up with a solution

Answer (score -1):

i hope its not too late..i used this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) to solve the problem.
1) Create a class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
        controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
        isValidName = true;
        }

    return isValidName;
    }
}
```

2. Edit your views

   ```
   <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

       ...

       <button id="loginBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="action:Login">Log in</button>   
   </form>

   <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

       ...

       <button id="registerBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="action:Register">Log in</button>   
   </form>
   ```
3. Add these to controller

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Login")]
   public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model) { ... }

   [HttpPost]
   [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Register")]
   public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) { ... }
   ```